# What is the best way to display the currency symbol locale-dependent?

Tags: java, jsf, currency

I would like to display the currency symbol ($, €) dependent on the current browser locale.
What is the best approach to do so?

I tried:

```
locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
System.out.println(locale); //gives: "en"
Currency.getInstance(locale).getSymbol(); //java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Currency.getInstance(locale.GERMANY).getSymbol(); //gives €
```

How can I get the symbol based on locale dependent browser setting (which is "en" here)?

**Update**

```
locale.getLanguage() > "de"
locale.getDefault() > "de_DE"
```

Nevertheless, `Currency.getInstance(locale).getSymbol();` fails.

Comment: As you're using JSF, why don't you just use `<f:convertNumber>`?

Comment: @BalusC I just want to display the symbol based on locale, without any number (at least in this output tag)! Or is that possible with convertNumber too?

Comment: @membersound `getLanguage()` is not interesting since you cannot map from languages to currency as I've told you in my answer yesterday. `getDefault()` is not interesting since this is a static method and returns your VM's default locale. This has nothing to do with your current locale instance. The only interesting thing is the country-part of your locale. You get that by calling `locale.getCountry()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currency depends on the Country-Part of Locale. Since `en` does not contain a country part it is an illegal argument for creating a Currency instance.

In other words: Would you expect `$`, `US$`, `AU$` or `£` for Locale "en"? Or something else? There is no currency for "English". There are currencies for the US, GB, Australia and so on but not for English.

**Edit**
If the user configured his browser properly then you'll get indeed a Locale with both: Country and Language Part (e.g. `en-US`). These locales you can use the way you've done it in your question.

BUT you should consider using Geotargeting based on IP-Address. There exist databases like [GEO-IP](http://software77.net/geo-ip/) and [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geoip_country). Be aware that there are differences - an US student on semester abroad in Germany surfing with his laptop. His browser may return `en-US` but a GEO-IP database will target most probably to `Germany`. But maybe this is exactly what you want?!

Finally you can use one of these approaches as primary targeting factor and the second as backup. When both fail then switch to a default (e.g. US$)

Comment: Ok, how instead can I display a locale-dependent currency symbol? I mean, as of now I did not find anything, but for sure there has to be a possibility to do so? Eg someone from europe goes to the website: display €, someone from US > $?

Comment: I added more info to my answer. Let me know if I could help you.

Comment: This is interesting, however sufficient would be to just display the symbol according to default browser language. I will provide a menu later on to let the user change the lang if he wants to. Even the localisation works at present. No matter if I set my browser to de-de, or en-us, en-uk, I can never retrieve the currency symbol. See my updated code.

Comment: @membersound `getDefault()` is a static method and has nothing to do with your Locale instance. `locale.getCountry()` must return the ISO 3166 2-letter country code or you cannot create a `Currency` instance from that locale. And `getCountry()` should return `US` when your locale is `en-US` since that is the country part.